# C++ Simple based scripting for RPG game actions?

Tags: c++, syntax, scripting, token

I am working on a video game called Tibia and I pretty much got the basic things of the game server, but now I need to be able to develop actions or so scripting, but very simplified nothing fancy or difficult, I don't like messy things.

Currently the community of this video game have achieved access to original files of it's scripting environment and it's like this:

```
Collision, IsCreature (Obj2) -> Teleport(Player,[47,14,1])
```

The scripting or syntax parser from this closed-source environment uses is a simple token based class, which looks for tokens and reads accordingly based on code.

Tokens are as follows:

A-Z = IDENTIFIER

0-9 = NUMBER

" = STRING

Anythig else = SYMBOL

And it's used like follows:

```
// This is a sample to use with the code below:
// USERNAME = "ROBERT"
//

nextToken(); // Looks for next token type

if (token == IDENTIFIER) {
    readSymbol(); // This reads =
    readString(); // This reads text inside "
}
```

What it basically does is loop in a char* array and look for tokens, I hope this is easy to understand.

What I am looking to achieve is a way to organize in my C++ code the functions with parameters given in the script file, like if I have this on a script file:

```
// Conditions -> Actions
IsPosition([10,20,7]) -> TeleportPlayer(Player,[25,10,30])
```

Know a way to gather this function with it's parameters to use in my game world environment? Like after I read this script file save the particular conditions and actions to check somewhere else on my code if the conditions accomplish and then do the following actions? Like check if the player is standing in Position and then teleport the player (which is what is written in the script file)

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: This is probably too broad a question for SO, but briefly, I'd recommend using a preexisting scripting language instead of rolling your own. 1) Read up on how to embed Lua in your application. 2) Decide what C++ functions you want to export to Lua. 3) Have fun scripting.

Comment: Sorry if I can't explain myself better with this complexity, if I have TeleportPlayer function in a text file and a IsPosition condition, how can I parse this function and it's parameters on my C++ code, and then in a different part of my C++ code check on my scripts list if any of the conditions meet and then interpret the actions written in the script file to the player?

Comment: @RaúlSanpedro Write a parser and runtime? If you want to interpret the file, you need to define the grammar in terms of expressions and/or statements, have a class representing each type of grammatical object, and a runtime class that is capable of taking such an object and executing/evaluating it. That's as specific as I can get without actually writing the whole thing for you.

Comment: Aren't there around any examples of parsing and runtime ?

Comment: here is an example of something similar: https://github.com/gemrb/gemrb/tree/master/gemrb/core/GameScript

its over 10,000 lines of code :)

Comment: oh, and here is the documentation for the scripting language that example uses: http://iesdp.gibberlings3.net/scripting/actions/bg2actions.htm